# What happens when an already locked sk_buff list is manipulated

Tags: list, sockets, linux-kernel, locking

I've an sk_buff list and doing some operation on it by owning it's lock. Another function (maybe called due to an interrupt) tries to do some operation on this list while my lock is still held.

What will happen in this case? Will the program get stuck because the interrupt function cannot acquire a lock to the list and hence cannot proceed?

Comment: I hope an interruption function is aware of such locking and prevent to stuck the system. What is this another function you have in mind? One of yours?

Comment: For example, I'm processing an ACK and going through the sk_buff list to find and delete the acked packet. However, before this function is complete, I receive another ACK which will interrupt this process and seek to delete another sk_buff from the list. Wouldn't this lead to a clash as my first ACK had already locked the sk_buff list?